# Is there any catch on using `zgemm3m` vs regular `zgemm`?

Tags: linear-algebra, performance, floating-point, blas, intel-mkl

I've just (to my embarrassment) encountered a BLAS-like extension of a matrix-matrix product subroutine [`gemm`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-cblas-gemm) in Intel MKL: [`gemm3m`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-cblas-gemm3m). This subroutine (particular versions: `cgemm3m` and `zgemm3m`) allows performing matrix-matrix multiplication for complex-valued matrices **using fewer arithmetic operations**.

[The `gemm3m` documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-cblas-gemm3m) claims that it

> ...**reduces** the time spent in matrix operations **by 25%**, resulting in significant savings in compute time for large matrices.

Looking at the provided error analysis in the Application Notes, I don't see anything "criminal":
$$
\hat{C}=\text{fl}(C_1+iC_2)=\text{fl}\big((A_1+iA_2)(B_1+iB_2)\big)=\hat{C}_1+i\hat{C}_2
$$
$$
||\hat{C}_1-C_1||\leq 2(n+1)u||A||_\infty||B||_\infty+\mathcal O(u^2)\\
||\hat{C}_2-C_2||\leq 4(n+4)u||A||_\infty||B||_\infty+\mathcal O(u^2)
$$
where $A,B,C\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ are complex matrices, $A_{1,2},B_{1,2},C_{1,2}\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ are their real and imaginary parts, respectively, $i=\sqrt{-1}$; $\hat{C}\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ and $\hat{C}_{1,2}\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ are the result of floating-point operations on $A$ and $B$ accoring to the `gemm3m` matrix-matrix multiplication algorithm. $|u|<\epsilon_\text{mach}$ if the floating-point arithmetic is IEEE-754 and no underflow\overflow happens.

So, is there any catch on using `zgemm3m` vs regular `zgemm`? Is there a situation where I should avoid using `zgemm3m`?

Comment: I didn't look into he details, but Higham's paper discusses this type of matrix multiplication: [Stability of a method for multiplying complex matrices with three real matrix multiplications](http://eprints.maths.manchester.ac.uk/348/1/0613043.pdf).

Comment: Example: $z_1=a+ib$ and $z_2=c+id$. If `a=0.1; b=13e-10; c=0.3; d=31e-10;` then in double precision (with octave): `a*d+b*c = 7.000000000000001e-10`, and `(a+b)*(c+d)-a*c-b*d = 6.999999983771085e-10`, which is less accurate.

Comment: There is also a recent algorithmic paper in ACM TOMS on the 3m and 4m methods for complex matrix-matrix multiplication. I forgot the authors (Field van Zee?) but they are from the Austin group doing linear algebra. If you can't find it, let me know and I'll find it for you!

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I think I found it: [3m-4m complex MMP, ACM TOMS](https://doi.org/10.1145/3086466). Thanks a lot for the lead!

Comment: @AntonMenshov: Yes, exactly!